# issue getting two audio files - write after end

Tags: node.js

> Error: write after end

I am trying to get it to play one audio file after another.

```
router.get('/a/:url(*)', (req, res) =>{
    res.set({
        "Content-Type": "audio/mp3",
       // 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunk',
      //  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
    });


    var url = req.params.url.substr(0); 
    console.log(url);
    https.get('https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/OUTOFAREA.mp3', response => {

        response.pipe(res);

    });
    https.get(url, response => {
        response.pipe(res);

    });
});
```

Comment: You have two GET requests to get files (mp3 files, I think so), and both write to `res`  to response to client, the error throw when a request finished while another on still streaming.

Comment: so should I write pipe the first one to a variable? and then just add it to the start of the other .get? @hoangdv

Comment: It is not simple, you have to join 2 streams into one, then response joined stream to client.